# Azure service bus and masstransit, same message, different namespace

Tags: azure, masstransit, servicebus

i'm using Azure service bus with masstransit it works perfectly if the message class type is inherited from the same project, but once the message is sent from another .net projet , so different namespace in "messageType" property, it goes automatically to deadletter and my consumer is unable to catch it,
what is the solution in this case ? because I cannot oblige different publishers (differents teams) to put the same namespace for that message type class
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html):

### Important

MassTransit uses the full type name, including the namespace, for message contracts. When creating the same message type in two separate projects, the namespaces must match or the message will not be consumed.

Comment: thank you Chris for your answer and for your time