# Consumer does not consume messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

This is my mass transit configuration in Program.cs:

```
    builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context,cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Message<IOrder>(f => f.SetEntityName("new-order"));
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("new-order", f => 
            {
                f.Consumer<ConsumeNewOrder>();
            });
        });
    });

   builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

Background service, which publishes new messages in a new-order queue:

```
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        readonly IBus _bus;
        public Worker(IBus bus)
        {
            _bus = bus;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while(!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await _bus.Publish<IOrder>(new { Id = 2 },
                    stoppingToken);
                await Task.Delay(3000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Consumer:

```
public class ConsumeNewOrder : IConsumer<IOrder>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IOrder> context)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Everything works locally in this project, but if I will split this code in 2 projects (copy `IOrder` and move consumer), it will not work, because consumer wont receive messages, but there will be `new-order_skipped` exchange and queue. The `_skipped` queue appears because consumer does not consume messages, but I don't know why. Please help

Comment: Where is your `builder.Services…..` code now ? Publisher or consumer?

Comment: @viveknuna it's in the same 'Program.cs ' file. That code works fine in 1 project, but I want another one to receive messages. Currently this project is consumer and publisher.

Comment: so your consumer doesn’t have this code?

Comment: @viveknuna when I split this code in 2 projects my publisher has a builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();. My consumer has a `ConsumeNewOrder`   and they both have `IOrder` with `builder.Services.AddMassTransit`.  In both projects I specified the name for the queue (`new-order`).

Comment: can you show your consumer code? And show the OnStart method of the consumer service

Comment: @viveknuna

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context,cfg) =>
    {
         cfg.Message<IOrder>(f => f.SetEntityName("new-order"));
         cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("new-order", f =>
         {
             f.Consumer<ConsumerService>();
         });
     });
});

- code in the consumer `Program.cs`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248185/discussion-between-killsan-and-vivek-nuna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many of these answers, but I [picked the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70941223/1882).

Messages **MUST** be the same type, including namespace. It's [right at the top in bold](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html) in the documentation.

When you split into two projects, your message types *must* share a namespace.

Also, ensure that all message entity names are configured the same in both the producer and the consumer (your `cfg.Message<IOrder>(f => f.SetEntityName("new-order"));` method).