# MassTransit not sending message to queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit, .net-7.0

I have two seperate services, a billing service and a user service. I want to send a message to the user service once someone's monthly subscription is payed. Both services are made in .net 7. For some reason my publisher (billing service) is not sending messages to my RabbitMQ, however, my consumer (user service) is consuming messages if i send a message with the RabbitMQ management console.

**Publisher (billing service) code:**

Configuring MassTransit in **program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
    config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672");


    });
});
```

Publishing message in controller **TransactionController.cs**

```
namespace service_billing.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TransactionController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ITransactionService _transactionService;
        private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

        public TransactionController(ITransactionService transactionService, IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
        {
            _transactionService = transactionService;
            _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody]Transaction transaction)
        {
            await _publishEndpoint.Publish<Transaction>(transaction);

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Every tutorial and post on this issue has a shared library between the publisher and the consumer with the model that is published and consumed. But since i am building two seperate services i cannot have this. Instead i created two identical classes in each service which leads to RabbitMQ creating two exchanges. Could this be the problem why i cannot send any messages to the queue? I am not very experienced in RabbitMQ so i am completely stuck on this issue.

[image]

If this is the problem, is there a way to use MassTransit between two seperate services without a shared library? And if this is not the problem, what could i be doing wrong here?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70941223/1882 - TLDR, same namespace + type name, even if in separate projects.

Comment: So that basically makes MassTransit useless for horizontal scaling my services seperately?

Comment: Not at all, you just have to follow the rules for message naming.